Logic Code Puzzle: PIANO -> KRBML?
In a certain code language, if "PIANO" is written as "KRBML", then how will "PRIME" be written in the same code language?
Options:
a) TRJCK
b) TRKCK
c) TRJGO
d) TRJKC

rot13(sbe CVNAB -> XEOZY, vg frrzf gur Agu yrggre bs gur nycunorg vf znccrq gb gur 27-Agu. (C->X) = (16->11), (V->E) = (9->18), naq fb ba. Gur bayl rkprcgvba vf N->O.)

@matt_rule but it doesnt work with the options does it?

Welcome to Puzzling, take our [tour]! Could you please provide proper attribution for this question?

One possible answer is

 A - TRJCK

Reason:

 For a 5 letter word, consider the alphabet position  of each letter
 for example PIANO -> 16 9 1 14 15 and call them a b c d e
 Encrypted word alphabet position (b+2) (a+2) (c+1)  (e-2) (d-2)
 For PIANO we get 11 18 2 13 12 -> K R B M L
 Applying the same to PRIME 16 19 9 13 5
 Gives 21 18 10 3 11 -> TRJCK

Trick was

 - To consider that first letter of initial is NOT encrypted as first letter of encrypted word..  Indice for this is that P, first letter of PIANO/PRIME is not converted to  the same initial for encypted word (K/T) while we have a R as second letter for in all propositions
 - Middle letter A->B and I->J in most proposals is also an indice of how middle letter can be transformed
 - Finally if we try to find one rule which matches for PIANO AND for PRIME with the one of the proposed solutions, we get the possible transformation described here

